# Convolutional Neural Network (CNN) in Julia

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, julia

I wrote an n-dimensional convolutional neural network from scratch in Julia (check out [the GitLab repo](https://gitlab.com/andy-sb/cnn) or [the GitHub repo](https://github.com/andy-sukowski/cnn)). It implements the following layer types:

- `Conv`: convolutional layer
- `Pool`: mean pooling, combine neuron clusters
- `Flatten`: flatten output of `Conv` to vector
- `Dense`: dense/fully connected layer

Even though it seems to work, it is unfortunately comparatively slow ([Flux.jl](https://github.com/FluxML/Flux.jl) is way faster), so I would love to receive feedback on both the coding style as well as possible performance enhancements.

### Convolutional gradient

$$ Y_k = \sigma[Z_k] = \sigma \left[ B_k + \sum_{j=1}^n X_j \star K_{kj} \right] $$

Based on the above equation, one can infer the partial derivatives of
the biases, kernels and activations in a convolutional layer with
respect to the loss / cost using the chain rule.

\begin{alignat*}{2}
    &\frac{\partial C}{\partial Z_k} &&= \sigma'[Z_k] \odot \frac{\partial C}{\partial Y_k} \\[8pt]
    &\frac{\partial C}{\partial B_k} &&= \frac{\partial C}{\partial Z_k} \\[8pt]
    &\frac{\partial C}{\partial K_{kj}} &&= X_j \star \frac{\partial C}{\partial Z_k} \\[8pt]
    &\frac{\partial C}{\partial X_j} &&= \sum_{k=1}^m \frac{\partial C}{\partial Z_k} * K_{kj}
\end{alignat*}

The same can be done for the **Dense gradient**, which you can find [here](https://gitlab.com/andy-sb/nn).

### Usage

First, initialize the neural network by chaining different layers and
storing them in a vector.

```
include("network.jl")

layers = [Conv(1 => 2, (28, 28), (5, 5)),
          Pool(2, 2),
          Conv(2 => 3, (12, 12), (5, 5)),
          Pool(2, 2),
          Flatten(3, (4, 4)),
          Dense(48 => 24),
          Dense(24 => 10)]
```

Then train the network on a data batch of type `Data` (defined in `network.jl`). The `train!()` function modifies the networks
parameters based on the average gradient across all data points.
Optionally, the learning rate `η` can be passed (default `η=1.0`). The
function returns the average loss of the network.

```
train!(layers, batch, η=2.0)
```

In order to achieve stochastic gradient descent, the `train!()` function
can be called from a `for`-loop. The `forward!()` and `loss()` function
can also be called manually.

### The CNN code

This is `network.jl`:

```
abstract type Layer end

include("utils.jl")
include("layers/conv.jl")
include("layers/dense.jl")
include("layers/flatten.jl")
include("layers/pool.jl")

# needed for Conv and Dense layers
Σ∇clear!(_ :: Layer) = nothing
Σ∇update!(_ :: Layer, _ :: Int) = nothing
Σ∇apply!(_ :: Layer, _ :: Float64) = nothing

loss(x, y)  = sum((x - y) .^ 2)
loss′(x, y) = 2 .* (x - y)

# batch of data points
Data = Vector{<:Tuple}

function forward!(layers :: Vector{<:Layer}, input :: Vector) :: Vector
    return foldl((inp, l) -> forward!(l, inp), [input, layers...])
end

function backprop!(layers :: Vector{<:Layer}, ∇output :: Vector) :: Vector
    return foldr(backprop!, [layers..., ∇output])
end

# data: [(input, expected)], only one batch!
function train!(layers :: Vector{<:Layer}, data :: Data; η=1.0 :: Float64) :: Float64
    Σ∇clear!.(layers)

    Σloss = 0
    for d in data
        output = forward!(layers, d[1])
        Σloss += loss(output, d[2]) / length(data)
        backprop!(layers, loss′(output, d[2]))

        Σ∇update!.(layers, length(data))
    end

    # play around with learning rate η
    Σ∇apply!.(layers, η)

    return Σloss
end
```

This is `utils.jl`:

```
ReLU(x)  = max(0, x)
ReLU′(x) = x >= 0 ? 1 : 0

σ(x)  = 1 / (1 + exp(-x))
σ′(x) = σ(x) * (1 - σ(x))

# recursive n-fold Cartesian product
cart(x) = Tuple.(x) # base case
cart(xs...) = [(i, j...) for i in xs[1], j in cart(xs[2:end]...)]
# alternatively, use Iterators.product():
# cart = collect ∘ Iterators.product

function one_hot(d :: Int, n :: Int) :: Vector{Int}
    out = zeros(n)
    out[d] = 1
    return out
end
```

This is `layers/conv.jl`:

```
import DSP # hopefully just temporary, as I want to write my own conv()

# convolutional layer: kernels, biases, gradient
mutable struct Conv <: Layer
    act       :: Function
    act′      :: Function

    input     :: Vector{<:Array{Float64}}
    kernels   :: Matrix{Array{Float64}}
    biases    :: Vector{Array{Float64}}
    z_maps    :: Vector{Array{Float64}}

    ∇kernels  :: Matrix{Array{Float64}}
    ∇biases   :: Vector{Array{Float64}}

    Σ∇kernels :: Matrix{Array{Float64}}
    Σ∇biases  :: Vector{Array{Float64}}
end

function Conv(dims :: Pair{Int, Int}, input_size :: Tuple{Vararg{Int}}, kernel_size :: Tuple{Vararg{Int}}, act = σ, act′ = σ′) :: Conv
    if length(input_size) != length(kernel_size)
        throw(DimensionMismatch("input_size and kernel_size must be the same length"))
    end

    output_size = input_size .- kernel_size .+ 1
    Conv(
        act,
        act′,
        [Array{Float64}(undef, input_size...) for _ in 1:dims[1]],
        [randn(kernel_size...) for _ in 1:dims[2], _ in 1:dims[1]],
        [zeros(output_size...) for _ in 1:dims[2]],
        Vector{Array{Float64}}(undef, dims[2]),
        Matrix{Array{Float64}}(undef, dims[2], dims[1]),
        Vector{Array{Float64}}(undef, dims[2]),
        [Array{Float64}(undef, kernel_size...) for _ in 1:dims[2], _ in 1:dims[1]],
        [Array{Float64}(undef, output_size...) for _ in 1:dims[2]]
    )
end

# # Because my custom xcorr() and full_conv() functions are currently
# # comparatively slow, I will use DSP.conv(), until I've optimized them.
#
# # return sum of product of kernel and region at certain index
# function apply_kernel(a :: Array{Float64}, k :: Array{Float64}, i :: Tuple{Vararg{Int}})
#   region = range.(i, i .+ size(k) .- 1)
#   return sum(a[region...] .* k)
# end
#
# # cross-correlation: sliding dot product
# function xcorr(a :: Array{Float64}, k :: Array{Float64})
#   indices = cart(range.(1, size(a) .- size(k) .+ 1)...)
#   return apply_kernel.((a,), (k,), indices)
# end
#
# # full convolution: input padding and 180° kernel rotation
# function full_conv(a :: Array{Float64}, k :: Array{Float64})
#   pad_a = zeros(size(a) .+ 2 .* size(k) .- 2)
#   pad_a[range.(size(k), size(a) .+ size(k) .- 1)...] .= a
#   return xcorr(pad_a, reverse(k))
# end

# full convolution: input padding and 180° kernel rotation
full_conv = DSP.conv

# n-dimensional cross-correlation using DSP.conv
function xcorr(a :: Array{Float64}, k :: Array{Float64})
    region = range.(size(k), size(a))
    return full_conv(a, reverse(k))[region...]
end

# forward pass, return output
function forward!(l :: Conv, input :: Vector{<:Array{Float64}}) :: Vector{<:Array{Float64}}
    if size.(l.input) != size.(input)
        throw(DimensionMismatch("dimensions of l.input and input must match"))
    end

    l.input .= input
    l.z_maps .= l.biases + sum.(eachrow(xcorr.(permutedims(l.input), l.kernels)))
    return (z_map -> l.act.(z_map)).(l.z_maps)
end

# l.input is set by forward!()
function backprop!(l :: Conv, ∇output :: Vector{<:Array{Float64}}) :: Vector{<:Array{Float64}}
    if size.(l.z_maps) != size.(∇output)
        throw(DimensionMismatch("dimensions of l.z_maps and ∇output must match"))
    end

    ∇input = zeros.(size.(l.input))
    ∇z_maps = (z_map -> l.act′.(z_map)).(l.z_maps)
    for k in eachindex(∇output)
        l.∇biases[k] = ∇z_maps[k] .* ∇output[k]
        for j in eachindex(l.input)
            l.∇kernels[k, j] = xcorr(l.input[j], ∇z_maps[k] .* ∇output[k])
            ∇input[j] += full_conv(∇z_maps[k] .* ∇output[k], l.kernels[k, j])
        end
    end
    return ∇input
end

# clear average gradient
function Σ∇clear!(l :: Conv)
    fill!.(l.Σ∇kernels, 0)
    fill!.(l.Σ∇biases, 0)
end

# update average gradient
function Σ∇update!(l :: Conv, data_len :: Int)
    l.Σ∇kernels += l.∇kernels / data_len
    l.Σ∇biases  += l.∇biases  / data_len
    return nothing
end

# apply average gradient
function Σ∇apply!(l :: Conv, η :: Float64)
    l.kernels -= η * l.Σ∇kernels
    l.biases  -= η * l.Σ∇biases
    return nothing
end
```

This is `layers/dense.jl`:

```
# dense layer: input, gradient
mutable struct Dense <: Layer
    act       :: Function
    act′      :: Function

    input     :: Vector{Float64}
    weights   :: Matrix{Float64}
    biases    :: Vector{Float64}
    zs        :: Vector{Float64}

    ∇weights  :: Matrix{Float64}
    ∇biases   :: Vector{Float64}

    Σ∇weights :: Matrix{Float64}
    Σ∇biases  :: Vector{Float64}
end

function Dense(dims :: Pair{Int, Int}, act = σ, act′ = σ′) :: Dense
    Dense(
        act,
        act′,
        Vector{Float64}(undef, dims[1]),
        randn(dims[2], dims[1]),
        zeros(dims[2]),
        Vector{Float64}(undef, dims[2]),
        Matrix{Float64}(undef, dims[2], dims[1]),
        Vector{Float64}(undef, dims[2]),
        Matrix{Float64}(undef, dims[2], dims[1]),
        Vector{Float64}(undef, dims[2])
    )
end

# forward pass, return output
function forward!(l :: Dense, input :: Vector{Float64}) :: Vector{Float64}
    if length(l.input) != length(input)
        throw(DimensionMismatch("dimensions of l.input and input must match"))
    end

    l.input = input
    l.zs = l.weights * l.input + l.biases
    return l.act.(l.zs)
end

# l.input is set by forward!()
function backprop!(l :: Dense, ∇output :: Vector{Float64}) :: Vector{Float64}
    if length(l.zs) != length(∇output)
        throw(DimensionMismatch("dimensions of l.zs and ∇output must match"))
    end

    l.∇biases = l.act′.(l.zs) .* ∇output
    l.∇weights = l.input' .* l.∇biases
    return l.weights' * l.∇biases
end

# clear average gradient
function Σ∇clear!(l :: Dense)
    l.Σ∇weights .= 0
    l.Σ∇biases  .= 0
    return nothing
end

# update average gradient
function Σ∇update!(l :: Dense, data_len :: Int)
    l.Σ∇weights += l.∇weights / data_len
    l.Σ∇biases  += l.∇biases  / data_len
    return nothing
end

# apply average gradient
function Σ∇apply!(l :: Dense, η :: Float64)
    l.weights -= η * l.Σ∇weights
    l.biases  -= η * l.Σ∇biases
    return nothing
end
```

This is `layers/flatten.jl`:

```
mutable struct Flatten <: Layer
    len :: Int
    input_size :: Tuple{Vararg{Int}}
end

Flatten(len, input_size...) = Flatten(len, input_size)

# no side-effects, but named forward!() for consistency
function forward!(l :: Flatten, input :: Vector{<:Array{Float64}}) :: Vector{Float64}
    if l.len != length(input) || l.input_size != size(input[1])
        throw(DimensionMismatch("dimensions of the layer and input must match"))
    end

    a = vcat(reshape.(input, 1, size(input[1])...)...)
    return vec(a)
end

# no side-effects, but named backprop!() for consistency
function backprop!(l :: Flatten, ∇output :: Vector{Float64}) :: Vector{Array{Float64}}
    if l.len * prod(l.input_size) != length(∇output)
        throw(DimensionMismatch("dimensions of the layer and ∇output must match"))
    end

    a = reshape(∇output', l.len, l.input_size...)
    return [copy.(eachslice(a, dims=1))...]
end
```

This is `layers/pool.jl`:

```
# pooling layer: pool size
mutable struct Pool <: Layer
    pool_size :: Tuple{Vararg{Int}}
end

Pool(pool_size...) = Pool(pool_size)

# mean pooling: combine neuron clusters, discard border
function pool(a :: Matrix{Float64}, pool_size :: Tuple{Vararg{Int}}) :: Matrix{Float64}
    indices = cart((:).(1, pool_size, size(a) .- pool_size .+ 1)...)
    sums = [sum(a[range.(i, i .+ pool_size .- 1)...]) for i in indices]
    return sums ./ prod(pool_size)
end

# no side-effects, but named forward!() for consistency
function forward!(l :: Pool, input :: Vector{<:Array{Float64}}) :: Vector{<:Array{Float64}}
    return pool.(input, (l.pool_size,))
end

# no side-effects, but named backprop!() for consistency, also kinda ugly
function backprop!(l :: Pool, ∇output :: Vector{<:Array{Float64}}) :: Vector{<:Array{Float64}}
    ∇input = fill(zeros(size(∇output[1]) .* l.pool_size), length(∇output))
    indices = cart(range.(1, size(∇input[1]))...)
    for i in eachindex(∇input), j in indices
            ∇input[i][j...] = ∇output[i][ceil.(Int, j ./ l.pool_size)...] / prod(l.pool_size)
    end
    return ∇input
end
```

### Testing with MNIST dataset

I added the following example of classifying [the MNIST dataset](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MNIST_database) using the above network to [the Git repository](https://gitlab.com/andy-sb/cnn/-/blob/main/examples/mnist.jl). You might want to reduce the number of batches, depending on your computing resources.

```
using Printf
using MLDatasets

include("../network.jl")

layers = [Conv(1 => 2, (28, 28), (5, 5)),
          Pool(2, 2),
          Conv(2 => 3, (12, 12), (5, 5)),
          Pool(2, 2),
          Flatten(3, (4, 4)),
          Dense(48 => 24),
          Dense(24 => 10)]

# load MNIST dataset from MLDatasets
train_x, train_y = MNIST(split=:train)[:]
inputs = [[Float64.(train_x[:, :, i])] for i in 1:size(train_x, 3)]
expected = one_hot.(train_y .+ 1, 10)
data = collect(zip(inputs, expected)) :: Data

# number of batches: 60000 / batch_size
batch_size = 10
batches = copy.(eachcol(reshape(data, batch_size, :)))

Σloss = Vector{Float64}(undef, length(batches))
# change number of batches, if needed
@time for i in eachindex(batches[begin:6000])
    Σloss[i] = train!(layers, batches[i], η=2.0)
    @printf "Σloss[%d] = %.12f\n" i Σloss[i]
end
```

> **Note**
> Unfortunately, the syntax highlighting seems to be broken for the Julia programming language on the Code Review Stack Exchange. You can either copy and paste the code into a text editor, or view it [on my GitLab](https://gitlab.com/andy-sb/cnn) or [on my GitHub](https://github.com/andy-sukowski/cnn).